# Powershell, I reading a line which is a group the the following lines are members

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I currently have a text document with all of the groups in our environment and their members that have the permissions/accessrights to modify memberships.

The format of the text document is as follows:

```
group1

member1

member2

member3

blankline

group2

member4

member2

member1

blankline

group3

member6

blankline
```

I am trying to read in the group, then verify that each member is actually in the group with the `-managedby` attribute.

```
$List = Get-Content $File

For ($i=0; $i -lt $List.length; $i++)
{
    Get-qADGroup $List[$i]
    $i += 1
    If($List[$i] -eq " "){
        Write-Host "test"
        }
    else{
            do{
                Write-Host $List[$i]
                $i += 1
            }until ($List[$i] -eq " ")
        }
        #$count = 0
        #$i += $count + 1

}
```

Comment: you indicated you were trying, but did not post any attempts

Comment: Currently, I only have it reading the contents from the file and looping through but I doesn't decipher between which one is the group name and which ones are the members.

Comment: Yes, that is the logic you have to code yourself. You could accomplish this with if statements... `if($list[$count] -eq " ")` Then the next line must be the group, and every subsequent line must be member, until the next space...

Comment: I have it so that it prints all the members of the group out after the distribution group but it seems like the get-distributiongroup call is only happening for the very first one.

Answer (score 0):

This will leave you with an object `$Groups` that will have records for each group, and it's members as an array within that record so you can do a `foreach($group in $groups){get-qadgroup $group|compare-object $_ $group.members}` or some such. to find the differences.

```
$List = gc $File
$Groups=@()
$Members=@()
$GroupName = $List[0]
$ii=1
while($Null -eq $Null){
    if($List[$ii]){
        $Members+=$List[$ii]
        $ii++
    }else{
        break
    }
}
$Group=[PSCustomObject]@{Group=$GroupName;Members=$Members}
$Groups+=$Group
$Blanks = for($i=0; $i -lt $list.count;$i++){if(!$List[$i]){$i}}
foreach($Blank in $Blanks){
    $Members = @()
    $GroupName = $List[$Blank+1]
    $ii=2
    while(($Blank+$ii) -le $List.Count){
        if($List[$Blank+$ii]){
            $Members+=$List[$Blank+$ii]
            $ii++
        }else{
            $Group=[PSCustomObject]@{Group=$GroupName;Members=$Members}
            $Groups+=$Group
            break
        }
    }
}
```